# Can someone tell me why my click event is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Getting type error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

after clicking the "Click" button. How can I fix this?

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML("This is text");
});
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
<button id="btn">Click </button>
<form name="myForm">
  Select output mode: <input type="radio" name="output" value="printer" checked /> Printer
  <input type="radio" name="output" value="scanner" /> Scanner
</form>
```

Comment: Check your browser console, it'll tell you. You're trying to assign a listener to an element before the element's been created in the HTML. Put the script in a separate file and give it the `defer` attribute. Also, you have no jQuery here, please tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: You should have an error like `VM99:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` in your console

Comment: One way to fix this is to move your script to the bottom of `body` tag

Comment: In addition to @CertainPerformance's note: It's invalid HTML to have a `script` tag as the direct child of the `html` tag. `script` tags must be in `head` or `body`. Putting your script tag at the very end of `body`, just prior to the closing `</body>` tag, is best unless you have a reason to do something else, and it would correct the first problem above. The second problem is that `innerHTML` isn't a function, it's a property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "This is text";` as `innerHTML` is not a function but a property of the `getElementById()`.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "This is text";
})
```

```html
<p id="para"> </p>
<ul id="myList">

    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
<button id="btn">Click </button>
<form name="myForm">
    Select output mode: <input type="radio" name="output" value="printer" checked /> Printer
    <input type="radio" name="output" value="scanner" /> Scanner

</form>
```